# Android Suporting older SDK where the method is not available

Tags: android

I've been looking for an answer but have not found a way to do it yet I hope somebody could point me in the right direction

I want support sdk8 and up, there is this method **createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord**
from the **android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice** library that is supported on SDk10 and up only

Quick and dirty is make the minSDK=10 but I dont want to leave my users with older devices out in the cold

I've seen pretty involved(or should I say wacky) ways of attempting this , reflections??? but they all fail for me the simplest way I thought would be:

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=10)
{
    BluetoothDevice device;
    Class myC = ClassforName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice")
    Method myM = myC.getDeclaredMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord");
    BluetoothSocket bb = (BluetoothSocket)myM.invoke(device, MYUUID);
}
```

But it throws a NoSuchExceptionMethod, so it looks like maybe the library has to have other name???? or how would you handle this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: it seems like you are missing the parameters of the method... UUID.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to increase your `minSDK` version you have either to wrap your calls with reflection ...

```
BluetoothDevice device;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
   Class myC = ClassforName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice")
   Method myM = myC.getDeclaredMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", 
                                       new Class[] { UUID.class } );
   BluetoothSocket bb = (BluetoothSocket)myM.invoke(device, MYUUID);
}
```

... or you provide an (abstract) class `android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice` that has only some empty method stubs. That allows you to compile your source without any errors. During run time the virtual machine will try to load that class from the system.

```
public abstract class BluetoothDevice {

    BluetoothDevice () {
    }

    public void createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID uuid) {
    }
}
```

The class has to be place in *root-source*/android/bluetooth. In any case it's important that you restrict any call to the right OS version (see my code above) otherwise you might get an `NoSuchExceptionMethod` -exception.

Finally: don't forget the signature (parameters) of the method (in `getDeclaredMethod()`).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks!!! the abstract class sounded cool but it didn't work.  The other method doesn't give a syntax error anymore but BT does not work probably I should  go on that side

Comment: Implementing the abstract class can be quite tricky 'cause usually you cannot instantiate it directly and there are situation where is won't work well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass also the declared parameters

```
Class myC = ClassforName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice")
Method myM = myC.getDeclaredMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord",UUID.class);
```